# Заливка цветом при нажатии на овальную кнопку

Tags: android, xml, button

Есть вот такой код:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid android:color="#266eff"/>
                <corners android:radius="10dp" />
            </shape>
        </item>
 </selector>
```

Создающий вот такой фон

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Требуется изменить цвет при нажатии и сохранить закругленные края при этом. Не хватает опыта.

Но есть пример, работающий для квадратной кнопки:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <item android:drawable="@color/blue" android:state_pressed="true"/>
  <item android:drawable="@color/AliceBlue" android:state_focused="true"/>  
  <item android:drawable="@color/Azure"/>

</selector>
```

Готов послушать какое-нибудь решение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
            <corners android:radius="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#266eff" />
            <corners android:radius="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```